# Best practices for removing old activities out of a feed

Tags: getstream-io

What would be the best way to handle an activity lifecycle? Is it common to have a maintenance job that purges feed activities that are no longer relevant or out of scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes some people have done it that way. Alternatively you can leave all the data there (though you might have to pay for additional storage if it gets really big).